# Using inode number to locate hardlinks

Tags: unix, find, inode

How can I use the inode number to locate all hardlinks to the file "file.txt" in my home directory?

Answer (score 1):

To find all files in your home directory with inode number *N*, use either

```
find ~ -maxdepth 1 -inum N
```

(home directory only) or

```
find ~ -xdev -inum N
```

(includes subdirectories).

The switch `-xdev` prevents finding files with the same inode number on different file systems, since they're not the hardlinks we're looking for.

To find all hardlinks to *file.txt*, you can use

```
find -inum "$(stat -c %i file.txt)"
```

with or without the `-maxdepth` switch.

See:

- [man find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find)
- [man stat](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?stat)

Comment: I'd add `-xdev`, for completeness in the general case. By definition, hard links will be on the same file system. (Though in this **particular** case, home dirs are very unlikely to span filesystems).